# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

Y'all apparently never got one of these. I thought I covered you in the sweep, but, whoops. Well, let's get you off to a fresh start at a full cycle instead of midway, then, at least.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting reads and resources for skeptics
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2025).

Comment: The answers template doesn’t seem to show up automatically (yet?).

Comment: @Konrad Currently, yeah it doesn't. Since this is the first time the site has had one, the auto-function isn't hooked up yet. I'll be getting that hooked up once I get the thread itself hooked up to run the ads.

Comment: Should I be seeing the mouseover text on mouseover? I'm not. (Chrome, Firefox and IE all tested.)

Comment: @TimFarley: Opportunity for free plugs for http://WhatsTheHarm.net and http://mywot.com?

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Google Scholar Web Search: Stand on the shoulders of giants]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Welcome to New Users' Guide]

Comment: If this encourages a graphic designer to scream in horror, and rush to submit a nicer looking version, my job here is done.

Comment: It's pretty terrible... :-)

Comment: English Language & Usage have just filed a trademark complaint over the colour being used for the background.

Answer (score 2):

[image: FAQ: Attributes of a Good Question]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Cochrane are an unaffiliate resource provide very useful meta-analyses for medical research questions.]

Comment: Oh, I get it now. We can advertise anything! This is an opportunity to plug the web-sites, podcasts and the like which we can't normally discuss because we aren't about discussing skepticism, we are about skeptically discussing claims.

Comment: I see a problem here. it says "we recommend" as if the users of Skeptics (us) recommend it, since we didn't (to the best of my knowledge" decided formally to recommend this site, I think that that that line should be removed.

Comment: @Ilya, you don't think 6 upvotes here would count? [What about the upvotes here?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/132/list-of-useful-sources-for-skeptics-se)

Comment: still no. The upvotes here are not for recommendation, especially since (IMO) this formulation sets this site apart, as the best or the most recommended. A good idea is  an ad for the meta question you linked to (the one with the sources) as in: "we recommend these sources". This ad gives me the feeling that the site that shows it recommends it more that other sources, which is not the case for us.

Comment: This might need a separate meta-question for a fuller discussion, because I think the same argument you provide could be applied to [other answers](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2517/23) to this question.

Comment: Just to clarify my position. I have no problem with an add for The Cochrane Collaboration". My only problem is with the phrase "we recommend" that appears in the add. I would have no objection to the exact same add, just without those 2 words. I haven't seen any other ad here that uses that phrase.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Italian Language & Usage. Please, click to commit]